# Is it a normal practice to ask to return credit card when closing a bank account?

Tags: credit-card, bank-account, austria

I have closed my bank account and the bank seems to have deliberatelly punished me for not returning the credit card to them. I would like to argue my case with them, but first I would like to know if it is a normal practice to request the clients to return an actual credit card when closing an account. Can't they just block it? I could surelly still use it online even if I did not have an actual card on me, couldn't I?

On the 19th of December I have requested that my bank account would be closed at the end of the year. I was asked to give back the little machine I use for transfering money as well as the cards. I said I would like to keep those for a few days, since my bank account would still be open till the end of the year. They agreed I could turn things in at the central branch a few days later.

On the 21st of December I have transfered most of my money to the new account, but left more than twice the amount of the credit card balance I would still need to pay. And then I brought the transfer machine to the central branch, and asked if there is anything else they need from me. They said no, so I kept my cards.

Normally, the money for my credit card are taken from my account on the 28th, latest the 30th, but never next month. This time they took the money on the 2nd of january, and then it immedietelly was returned back. My account was still not deleted at the time. They have transfered all my remaining money to the new account on the 3rd.

On the 7th of January I got a letter from the credit card company demanding the money. The money that was actually due + the late fees.

I have talked to my (ex-)bank about this situation, and they said, it was because I did not return the credit card. I cannot help but think, that they have deliberatelly punished me by taking back the money that was already send to the credit card company so that I would get the late fee.

Would such a situation be possible? it it normal for a bank to require the physical card be brought back to it, instead of just cancelling it?

Comment: When did you authorize them to transfer money from the deposit account to pay the credit card?  Do you have proof of that date (such as a confirmation email or confirmation number)?

Comment: The credit card was connected to the bank account, so money would be transfered every month automatically. I think the credit card company would take it automatically from the account. The last transfer that I have requested to be done was to my new bank account.

Answer (score 1):

If the agreement you signed when you opened the account stipulated that the physical card is the bank’s property, then it is the bank’s right to have it returned upon closing the account, unless Austrian law says otherwise.